# Button onclick not calling function

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

My button code looks like this:

```
<button onclick="submitFunction()">Submit</button>
```

And my function code like this:

```
function submitFunction() {
    alert("example");
}
```

I've been looking online for an answer and tried a bunch of things, but nothing seems to work. I'm just putting the alert there to see if the function is being called at all.
I'm using the following to link the files.

```
<script src="file.js"></script>
```

Comment: it ll work, some where in script file it may have syntax error

Comment: Just try to have your js file in the same folder where you have the html, it should work

Comment: Comment this line in your code `<script src="file.js"></script>` and check it work or not?

Comment: The files are in the same folder and I've checked the spelling multiple times to make sure it matches. I've also changed the name of the .js file since it used to be the same as the .html name. They need to stay separate files since this is homework. I've gotten other .js files linked to .html files before and I can't seem to figure out why these 2 won't link.

Answer (score 7):

Probably browser can not find your external js file, because of wrong path. Try to put function inside the `<head>` section of the page and if worked, The problem is wrong path to js file.

Comment: I added the function to the html head and it worked, but I've checked the file name and it matches. The files are in the same folder. Does it matter that the .html and .js files have the same name?

Comment: No, they can have different names. You can check for error and debug with Firebug.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write following `javascript` code between `<head>` tag and make sure your given javascript file have `valid path`.

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function submitFunction() {
      alert("example");
  }
</script>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kzrL5cb6/)**

Comment: This is homework and the js code needs to be in a separate file. The issue seems to be linking to the .js even though they are in the same folder and everything looks ok.

Answer (score 2):

Instead you can call jquery and call function externally in script tag.

Ex:

```
$("button").on("click",function(){alert("hi")})
```

Comment: This is homework and I can't use jquer. My homework is not even about this function, I just can't link my js file to my html file and it's a requirement to have the js code in a separate file.

Answer (score 2):

Give your function at the very beginning of your external js file .

Answer (score 2):

In case it helps anyone in the future, when having link problems like this I've found it useful to:

1. Add a HTML link to the file `<a href="file.js">file.js</a>` and click it in the browser to see where it takes you.
2. Remind it to look in the current directory (provided it is definitely in the current directory) with "./" `"./file.js"` (For some strange reason it seems to sometimes help—or I'm crazy—which is more likely.)

Answer (score 2):

If your function happens to be in the global scope, try adding `window.` before the function. Like this:

`<button onclick="window.submitFunction()">Submit</button>`

```
function submitFunction() {
    alert("example");
}
```

This worked for me.

I have seen other people specify the button type and then add return false after the function like this:

`<button type="button" onclick="window.submitFunction(); return false;">Submit</button>`
This didn't change anything for me, but It may work in your case. You could give it a try.

Comment: this worked for me! Do you know where the rules for this are specified?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, then realised the I was not giving the proper type attribute in the script tag, instead of giving tag as:

```
type="text/javascript"
```

I was giving it as:

```
type="text/script"
```